# Running a query for multiple datasets only different by ID (Big Query)

Tags: sql, arrays, loops, google-bigquery

I need to run the same select statement for multiple datasets in Big Query only different by ID (1568 - 3257 - 8432 etc.) This select statement also uses a join across tables from the same dataset. My question is how can we do this without using UNION ALL ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM test.1568.activity
INNER JOIN test.1568.employee on (activity.employee_id = employee.id)
```

Is there any possibility that we can create an array containing the id of different datasets, and then using a loop to process that statement for each dataset?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a script for it, which loops through and runs the query, like this:

```
DECLARE datasets ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE datasets_length INT64;

SET datasets = (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(schema_name) FROM `your-project-id.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`);
SET datasets_length = (SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(datasets));

WHILE i < datasets_length DO
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
    SELECT COUNT(1) table_count FROM `your-project-id.%s.__TABLES__`
  """, datasets[OFFSET(i)]);
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
```

This example counts the tables in each dataset in a project. You can change the in the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement for what you would like to run on every dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I'm able to process this script. May I also know how can I return it as only one result? Instead of going and clicking to view results for each dataset?